# Windows 11 Hard Drive Not Installed Error

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-11

I just installed a cumulative update for Windows 11 yesterday. But now when I try to boot it. It displays an error message as the following:

[image]

I have tried:

1. Disconnect the battery and the hard disk for 30s.
2. Reset the BIOS settings.

Both of them do not work.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out my problem. My SSD disk is broken, probably quality issue from the manufacturer. I checked on their Amazon review, there have been similar issues with the same product.

Basically, I just plugged another SSD back to my machine, and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the Microsoft offered you the Windows 11 update and that you did not make any system changes to force the computer to run Windows 11.

Then get the Dell Hardware test APP, make a bootable USB key from the Hardware APP and test all hardware, particularly the hard drive.

The bootable USB App bypasses operating system and checks all hardware.

It make be that the hard drive developed a hardware error at the last update (coincidence).

It seems reasonably clear the HDD has failed. You can also consider arbitrarily replacing it.

Comment: By Dell Hardware test APP? Do you mean this? https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ca/quicktest

Also, I am pretty sure that Windows 11 update was offered, I installed from the `Windows Update` center, and I did not install it manually by myself.

I will have to make a bootable USB key from another laptop? Since I can't boot from my current laptop

Comment: Yes:   Diagnostic Tools for Dell Laptops and Desktops

Enhanced Pre-Boot System Assessment (ePSA)

Comment: And I should have noted that you can make the bootable USB Key on any computer and then test your own. I added clarity to my answer.

Comment: They ask for an error code and a validation code. What should I put there?

Comment: It leads me to this page: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ca/pre-boot-analysis, and I am not sure what to do

Comment: Submit a query to Dell Support and have them provide the information you need. You really need to test hardware.  Try HDDScan:   https://www.lifewire.com/hddscan-review-2624562    ... It came up in a search for offline tools.  See if you can adapt this. Dell Support is your best bet.  They probably need to know the machine model to get the correct HD test for it.